# Selenium - Permission denied to get property HTMLDocument.readyState

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, browser-automation

We are doing some automation using Selenium (for Firefox) and recorded a script to playback. This was working fine until the provider roled out some new changes. Now we get the following error, not sure what this means...

```
    [info] Executing: |waitForPopUp | LookuphdnProductId1 | 40000 |
  -->[error] Permission denied for <https://books.zoho.com> to get property HTMLDocument.readyState
    [info] Executing: |selectWindow | name=LookuphdnProductId1 | <br/>
  -->[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js, lineNumber -> 840
```

Anybody with experience in browser automation or Selenium throw some hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

via [this blogpost](http://www.woloszyn.org/2008/04/22/selenium-and-the-permission-denied-to-get-property-locationhref-problem/) and [Selenium FAQ](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+core+FAQ#SeleniumCoreFAQ-Whycan%27tIgetSeleniumCoreteststoworkwithGoogle%3F):

It's basically a problem with [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which is a design limitation of Selenium RC (and therefore also of Selenium IDE). The thing is that Selenium runs all your commands as Javascript - and Javascript can't be run cross-domain. But you obviously change the domain somewhere in the test.

Don't you somewhere try to open an address like this: `http://www.somedomain.com/link=www.google.com`? If yes, you might want to open `http://google.com` right away. If you were clicking on a link with such a href, try to dig the link out and open the url "manually" in the script. Or use Firefox with some addon that does it for you, I've seen some.

If there's just a redirect to another website/domain, then you're in a pickle. If you start on `foo.com` and are redirected via some link to `bar.org` then you must not use the `andWait` command and open `bar.org` again manually in the script (so it runs on that domain and has the right access rights).

By the way, Selenium 2 (WebDriver) doesn't have this limitation.

Comment: I suspected it, but I don't have any 'open' URL in the script, the script assumes you are in the right page/URL and starts clicking on the right controls. In this case should I manually set the domain/url? Thanks

Comment: To be absolutely honest, I have no idea. There is a bunch of things you can try. If you don't need to work in the popup window, then simply get rid of the "andWait" and close the window. If you need to, try to split the testcase in two - one opening the popup, one starting there / opening the window cleanly from URL (if there's no POST data, that is). Good luck, anyway, please post your solution after you have it. Or start a new question on how to overcome this :).